# Grails Quartz2 Session Problems

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have some problems with Grails 2.2.3 and the Quartz2-Plugin.
In my code i create a job that gets some domain classes as parameters and shall load products via ftp-server and add them to my domain class.
The main problem i got was a hibernate session problem. I have done some research about the hibernate session problem and came to solutions to do that with "withTransaction" or i tried to inject sessionFactory to my job-class but this all haven't helped.

Currently i set the mapping of my associated objects to lazy: false, but for example my Company-Domain class contains a list of products which could be very big.

Because of my company-laws i can't set here code-snippets.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.

I created my own Scheduler with the SchedulerFactory for that by default no session was bind. So i remarked that and began to use the quartzScheduler by injecting it to my controller class and now it works.